How do I create a collection authority PDA that can create multiple collections and mint tokens to a list of accounts under the same merkle tree?
I wanted to find a way to create collections and mint tokens to that collection but instead of having a single collection per merkle tree I want to user multiple collections with different nft metadata and different accounts to mint to. What would be the best way to go about it?
This is some code I put together using this github repo:
solana-developers/compressed-nfts
The minting function
async function mintNftsToReceivers(
  connection: WrapperConnection,
  payer: Keypair,
  treeAddress: PublicKey,
  collectionDetails: {
    mint: PublicKey;
    metadata: PublicKey;
    masterEditionAccount: PublicKey;
  },
  receivers: PublicKey[]
) {
  const [treeAuthority] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([treeAddress.toBuffer()], BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID);
  const [bubblegumSigner] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("collection_cpi", "utf8")], BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID);

  for (let i = 0; i < receivers.length; i++) {
    const receiver = receivers[i];
    const initialBalance = await connection.getBalance(payer.publicKey);

    const compressedNFTMetadata = createNftMetadata(payer.publicKey, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));

    const mintIx = createMintToCollectionV1Instruction(
      {
        payer: payer.publicKey,
        merkleTree: treeAddress,
        treeAuthority,
        treeDelegate: payer.publicKey,
        leafOwner: receiver,
        leafDelegate: receiver,
        collectionAuthority: payer.publicKey,
        collectionAuthorityRecordPda: BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID,
        collectionMint: collectionDetails.mint,
        collectionMetadata: collectionDetails.metadata,
        editionAccount: collectionDetails.masterEditionAccount,
        compressionProgram: SPL_ACCOUNT_COMPRESSION_PROGRAM_ID,
        logWrapper: SPL_NOOP_PROGRAM_ID,
        bubblegumSigner,
        tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
      },
      {
        metadataArgs: Object.assign(compressedNFTMetadata, {
          collection: { key: collectionDetails.mint, verified: false },
        }),
      }
    );

    try {
      const tx = new Transaction().add(mintIx);
      tx.feePayer = payer.publicKey;

      const txSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [payer], {
        commitment: "finalized",
        skipPreflight: true,
      });

      console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txSignature}?cluster=devnet`);

      const balanceAfterMint = await connection.getBalance(payer.publicKey);
      const mintCost = (initialBalance - balanceAfterMint) / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
      console.log(`Cost of minting to receiver ${receiver.toBase58()}: ${mintCost} SOL`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`\nFailed to mint compressed NFT to receiver ${receiver.toBase58()}:`, err);
    }
  }
}

Create Nft Metadata
function createNftMetadata(creator: PublicKey, index: number) {
  if (index > uris.length) {
    throw new Error("Index is out of range");
  }

  const uri = uris[index];

  // Compressed NFT Metadata
  const compressedNFTMetadata: MetadataArgs = {
    name: "CNFT",
    symbol: "CNFT",
    uri: uri,
    creators: [{ address: creator, verified: false, share: 100 }],
    editionNonce: 0,
    uses: null,
    collection: null,
    primarySaleHappened: false,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    isMutable: false,
    tokenProgramVersion: TokenProgramVersion.Original,
    tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
  };

  return compressedNFTMetadata;
}

The Create Collection Function
export type CollectionDetails = {
  mint: PublicKey;
  metadata: PublicKey;
  masterEditionAccount: PublicKey;
};

export async function getOrCreateCollectionNFT(
  connection: Connection,
  payer: Keypair
): Promise<CollectionDetails> {
  const envCollectionNft = process.env["COLLECTION_NFT"];

  // Metaplex instance using payer as identity
  const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection).use(keypairIdentity(payer));

  if (envCollectionNft) {
    const collectionNftAddress = new PublicKey(envCollectionNft);
    const collectionNft = await metaplex
      .nfts()
      .findByMint({ mintAddress: collectionNftAddress });

    if (collectionNft.model !== "nft") {
      throw new Error("Invalid collection NFT");
    }

    return {
      mint: collectionNft.mint.address,
      metadata: collectionNft.metadataAddress,
      masterEditionAccount: (collectionNft as Nft).edition.address,
    };
  }

  // Select a random URI from uris
  const randomUri = uris[Math.floor(Math.random() * uris.length)];

  // Create a regular collection NFT using Metaplex
  const collectionNft = await metaplex.nfts().create({
    uri: randomUri,
    name: "Collection NFT",
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    updateAuthority: payer,
    mintAuthority: payer,
    tokenStandard: 0,
    symbol: "Collection",
    isMutable: true,
    isCollection: true,
  });

  fs.appendFileSync(
    ".env",
    `\n${"COLLECTION_NFT"}=${collectionNft.mintAddress.toBase58()}`
  );

  return {
    mint: collectionNft.mintAddress,
    metadata: collectionNft.metadataAddress,
    masterEditionAccount: collectionNft.masterEditionAddress,
  };
}


could you provide more clarity on your question?
